# Tags for the European long distance trails

Tags: discussion, tags

We have a [question](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/18308/what-route-does-the-e1-take-through-b%C3%B8rgefjell-national-park) about the [E1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E1_European_long_distance_path) and a (poor) [question](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/18280/i-am-researching-the-e4-path) about the [E4](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/18280/i-am-researching-the-e4-path).  We might get more questions about the various European E-routes, like we already have many about the more popular American long-distance trails such as the Pacific Crest Trail ([pct](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pct)).

The European E-routes mostly, if not exclusively, use pre-existing trails, farm tracks, roads, and at times passes through trailless backcountry (at least the E1 does).  Alternatives:

- [e1](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/e1)
- [trail-e1](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trail-e1)
- [route-e1](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/route-e1)
- [european-hiking-route-e1](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/european-hiking-route-e1)
- [european-trail-e1](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/european-trail-e1)
- Something else?

[image: European routes]

Answer (score 4):

I think there should not be a tag about the E1 trail in specific, but one for all European long distance trails. This is very broad, but E1 is also very broad, any question will most likely include more specifics about location (as the linked question does). I don't think there will be a considerable amount of traffic for every single path. The [official designations](http://www.era-ewv-ferp.com/walking-in-europe/e-paths/) seems to be [e-paths](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/e-paths), but that might be a bit unclear as a tag. On the other hand [european-long-distance-paths](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/european-long-distance-paths) is a mouthful. In between only [e-long-distance-paths](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/e-long-distance-paths) makes any sense to me. Maybe Charlie can do an analysis of tag length distribution on TGO for an easier (or not) decision :D

Comment: I agree that a single tag covering all e-paths would make more sense, as we don't have high traffic on those tags (for now).  However, [tag:e-long-distance-paths] or [tag:e-paths] makes me think of something electronic.  e-commerce, e-currency, e-mail.

Comment: @gerrit I agree. Personally, I would go with "european-long-distance-paths" despite its length.

Comment: Maybe [tag:european-trail] would do?  Although that might lead people to think any trail in Europe, tag wiki could clarify we mean the long distance trails.  Just like an "All-American trail" wouldn't be your 3 km walk in a local state park.

Comment: My vote would be for [tag:european-long-distance-paths]

Comment: Tag both e1 and e-paths. There’s also the GRs.