# Proposal: use european-long-distance-paths for all international long distance paths in europe

Tags: discussion, tags

### Introduction

Currently, the tag description for [european-long-distance-paths](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/european-long-distance-paths) reads:

> Use this tag for questions specific to one of the twelve international European long-distance paths. For long-distance paths entirely in one Europea country, such as GRs in France or Spain National Trails in the UK or LAWs in The Netherlands, use other, country-specific tags.

### Proposal

I propose we change this to allow also other international long distance paths in Europe, such as:

- Tour du Mont Blanc (France, Italy, Switzerland)
- Nordkalottleden (Sweden, Norway, Finland)
- Peaks of the Balkans (Albania, Montenegro, Kosovo/Serbia)

### Rationale

The tag [european-long-distance-paths](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/european-long-distance-paths) currently does not get much traffic.  At the time of writing, there are four open questions, of which one is not about one of "the twelve" but about the Tour du Mont Blanc.  I think people interested in European long distance paths with an E-number should also be interested in international European long distance paths without an E-number.

### See also

*[Tags for the European long distance trails](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1107/tags-for-the-european-long-distance-trails)*

---

Comment: I agree, but lets wait a few days to see what others want to say about it.

Comment: That makes sense!

Comment: I think we can go on with it. Do you know how many questions will be involved in adding the tag?